# Find derivative values when knowing anther function value

Tags: functions, derivatives

I have a problem as follow:
Suppose $f(-2)=0$, $f(0)=\pi$ and $f(2)=2\pi$ and $f'(x)={\sqrt{4-x^2}}$
A. If $h(x)=f(2\sin(x))$, what is $h'(0)$? Show clearly and completely how to find.

B. If $k(x)=2\sin(f(x))$, what is $k'(0)$? Show clearly and completely how to find.

Here what I did:

A. $h'(x)=f'(2sin(x))={\sqrt{4-(\sin x)^2}}$

At $x=0$ -> $h'(0) = {\sqrt{4-(\sin 0)^2}} = \sqrt4 = 2$

B. $k'(x)=2(\sin(f(x))\times f'(x)$

At $x=0$ -> $k'(0) = 2 \times \sin(\pi) \times {\sqrt{4-0^2}} = 0 $

Have I done it correctly? If not, could you show me how to? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not applying the chain rule correctly. Symbolically, it is $$(\operatorname{outer}(\operatorname{inner}(x)))' = \operatorname{outer}'(\operatorname{inner}(x))\cdot\operatorname{inner}'(x)$$ You should carefully identify what the outer and inner functions are in these cases.

Comment: So which one is wrong, could you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

$\int \sqrt(4-x^{2})$ and you obtain a function $f(x)+C$. Now, with preliminar conditions, you can find the value of constant C, replace $x$ for any value given and you can obtain C. After this, apply the chain rule.